# How can I apply changes from file A to file B?

Tags: git

I haven't come across this before, and my searches are not leading me down the right path.

Two of my developers created folders for the same module. One dev named the folder correctly 'moduleNameHere', the other did 'module name here'. They had PRs at the same time and no one noticed the overlap. There are now two files A.code and B.code within their own folders that should really be contained within one file. They could stay separate, but its *technically* against our standards as they affect the same area.

Is it possible to pick specific commits from file B.code and apply them to A.code?

I was attempting to do something with cherry picking, but I could figure out a way to alter the target in any fashion.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Don't "cherry pick". Keep it simple.  It sounds like the problem is just one mis-named directory.  Fine.  Just check out the latest/greatest, physically copy what you want, delete what you don't want, and check in the "clean" result.  Easy peasy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether there are better ways but you can [get the diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203), modify the file name in it and then [apply](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) it:

```bash
# save changes between first-commit and last-commit
git diff --output=changes.diff first-commit..last-commit A.code
```

Then, you edit the `changes.diff` file so it mentions the file `B.code` instead of `A.code`.

Finally, you tell git to apply the changes:

```bash
git apply changes.diff
```

This will only change the working tree, you'll still need to commit it.

Also, note that file `B.code` should have pretty much the same content as file `A.code` before the changes in order to do the changes cleanly. In any case, you should check whether everything has been applied correctly afterwards.

To improve your chances of success, you might want to [specify the algorithm for finding the diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-algorithmpatienceminimalhistogrammyers), e.g. with `--diff-algorithm=minimal`

If it fails, you probably need to apply the changes manually but `git diff` at least gives you a good overview on what you changed.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this to accomplish what I wanted, i.e. "merge" the files.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether the two versions happened to be in the same project/same branch.  But assuming they are, I would:

1. Commit and push both developers' versions to the remote. To ensure the remote has the latest version(s) of all source.
2. Pull the remote to one or the other's local project (or clone to a new, temp directory)
3. Manually copy the "best" version(s) of all source files into the "correct" directory
4. Manually DELETE the "bad" directory (and everything in it)
5. Commit and push the updated, "clean" project to the remote.  Be sure and provide a meaningful "commit" message.
6. "pull" to all other project(s)

Voila!  Done.